# Get the wrong return , SQL - if

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, if-statement

I have the next method:

```
    private bool bla()
{

    int Minbuy, ordersTillNow;
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=****;Password=****;Integrated Security=False;");
        string commandtext = "SELECT Minbuy FROM items WHERE main = 1";
        string commandtext2 = "SELECT ordersTillNow FROM items WHERE main = 1";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandtext, connection);
        SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(commandtext2, connection);

        connection.Open();

        Minbuy = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
        ordersTillNow = (int)command2.ExecuteScalar();

        if (Minbuy < ordersTillNow)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }



}
```

And the use of the method on page_ load:

```
        if (bla())
    {
        Image_V.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
       Image_X.Visible = true;
    }
```

The values on the result in query in the SQL is:

> MinBuy = 5
>
> ordersTillNow = 1

The weird thing is - nevermind what is the value in the db (i've changed the value to: MinBuy = 1 and ordersTillNow = 8) - it's display the image_v . (on the aspx page - both of the image visble set to false).

What is wrong in the code ?

The table desgin:

table name: items

columns: itemId(int) , main (bit) , MinBuy (int) , ordersTillNow(int) .

Comment: Can you show us the table structure? Is main the primaryKey in items table?

Comment: @ysrb: Yep, i added the structure to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2):

What I can think that might be the problem is that the result from the above SQL might return more than 1 row. Thus, it will give the wrong result.

Try changing the code to :

```
string commandtext = "SELECT TOP 1 Minbuy FROM items WHERE main = 1";
string commandtext2 = "SELECT TOP 1 ordersTillNow FROM items WHERE main = 1";
```

Instead of having 2 selects you can use one select

```
string queryString = "SELECT Minbuy, ordersTillsNow FROM items WHERE main = 1";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            MinBuy = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
            ordersTillsNow = int.Parse(reader[1].ToString());
            //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 on that. Run the selects in management studio and check that they return one row.

Comment: Yes, they are return one row.

Comment: Your first re-write (`TOP 1`) doesn't solve a multi-row problem, since there's no `ORDER BY`, and thus no guarantee that the row read by the second query will be the same row read by the first query.

Comment: Thanks. i tried and it not solve the issue. i dont know what is goin on with my code and why it seems it's not took the value from the sql. or maybe the prob is on the return from the code...

Comment: +1 on using the `using` on the `SqlConnection` - you should put `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` into `using` blocks as well....

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need:

```
if (bla())
{
    Image_V.Visible = true;
    Image_X.Visible = false;
}
else
{
   Image_V.Visible = false;
   Image_X.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: The problem is not on the if statement i think it's from the sql cmd, because i changed the values and the result is the same.

Comment: @Bside: separate testing of bla from image visibility: what does bla **actually** give...? **Not** what the page is doing. I think ypercube has a very relevant answr

Comment: @Bside: Have you tried printing the values (of Minbuy and ordersTillNow) that are returned?

Comment: @gbn: bla method is to display image_v \ image_x by the result of the two columns - MinBuy and ordersTillNow. if the ordersTillNow reach the number of minBuy - i want to display the image_v.

Comment: @Bside: That's a "requirement". Not a "test". image display isn't working: so check **that bla returns true/false as expected** befre thinking of the image. With your "unit test" that as a good developer you wrote first...

Comment: @gbn: thanks. can you give me an idea how to check the bla returns ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's hit the database only once, and get it to answer the question for us:

```
private bool bla()
{
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=****;Password=****;Integrated Security=False;"))
    {
        string commandtext = "SELECT CONVERT(bit,CASE WHEN Minbuy < ordersTillNow THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM items WHERE main = 1";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandtext, connection);
        connection.Open();
        return (bool)command.ExecuteScalar();    
    }
}
```

This code also makes sure to close the connection, that you were not previously taking care of. But if you're still not seeing the expected results, then as others have suggested, you need to check that the image display code is working as expected. Maybe have:

```
Image_V.Visible = bla();
Image_X.Visible = !Image_V.Visible;
```

instead.